# PowerShell 7.3.1 - Launching "pwsh.exe" does not load custom profile but loading PowerShell from Terminal loads the profile

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-11, microsoft

I have a custom PowerShell profile. Here is the gist.
[PowerShell Profile](https://gist.github.com/a-bhattacharya/707b2cefb433a4650ab4a5bd4a65b706)

Windows Terminal is configured to start in `%USERPROFILE%` directory. When I launch Terminal, PowerShell loads up as default with the oh-my-posh themes as configured.
[image]

But when I launch the "pwsh.exe" executable from "Run" or by searching, it loads up as follows.

[image]

I cannot figure out the cause.
I thought maybe it had something to do with the Execution Policy and set it to Unrestricted but that didn't help either.